# MongoDB - How does this simple MySQL data fit into a Doc object?

Tags: mongodb, structure, database

point of principle here I'm struggling with on Mongo.

I'm gently and manually putting in test data into a Mongo DB from my MySQL DB. So I have this data in MySQL:-

```
id\no\start\ratio\gol\fable\dble
488442\1\0000\6200\0\0\15
488444\2\6200\640\0\15\15
```

Sorry for the odd separator - but you get the idea.

If I then put this into Mongo - do I do

```
"doc" : { "id" : [ 488442, 488444 ], "no" : [ 1,2 ], "start" : [0000,6200] }
```

etc. I realise there's a lot 'do it how you like' with NoSQL, but is there a right answer to this simple question that could help more generally (plse dont close the thread)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there is no right and wrong answer for this.
However, I strongly recommend you read this document/tutorial here: [Mongo Schema Design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) and this [SQL to Mongo mapping chart](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart), that will help you understand the differences and similarities between analog concepts.

In mongo you should design your schema so that it fits your most common use case.

From your example, it seems that you are trying to map a Mongo document to a table in SQL. If there is no special reason, why you are doing this, I would stick to the more common: each row  of a SQL table is a single document in a Mongo collection. The most trivial way would be to just create a document per row and add something like this:

```
{"id": 488442, "no": 1, "start": 0000, "ratio": 6200, "gol": 0, "fable": 0, "dble": 15}
{"id": 488444, "no": 2, "start": 6200, "ratio": 640, "gol": 0, "fable": 15, "dble": 15}
```

in a collection with a name as your MySQL table. Of course it will be better, if you sit down and analyse a bit, whether there isn't a more suitable representation of your relational model, now that you do not have to comply to it.